# onActivityResult failed - Google Auth Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to authenticate my app with Firebase and Google accounts.I followed official tutorials and when I select my Google Sign In button, it shows me list of accounts and I select one of them and get that log message from onActivityResult method.

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("here is my client id")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: failed");
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .build();


mGoogleSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick:");
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
```

And outside onCreate method :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode = " + requestCode);
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: successful");
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign In Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: failed");
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle: " + account.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: successful");
                FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeTabActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure" + task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you log the `GoogleSignInResult` code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen before an edit it seemed like dev keys were in the code, maybe it was just a client ID actually. It looked like something private.

Comment: onActivityResult: requestCode = 9001
onActivityResult: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@46fc18f
onActivityResult: failed

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("here is my client id")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    GLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                            .setProviders(Collections.singletonList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()
                            ))
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);




        }
    });
```

onActivityResult

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        if (resultCode == ResultCodes.OK) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                Log.e("Login","Login canceled by User");
                return;
            }
            if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                Log.e("Login","No Internet Connection");
                return;
            }
            if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                Log.e("Login","Unknown Error");
                return;
            }
        }
        Log.e("Login","Unknown sign in response");
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: OnActivityResult is now deprecated, so this won't work, at least not in my case.